# REGEX min. 4 chars, max 11, allow space and special chars

Tags: regex

I have a regex on a RegularExpressionValidator .NET control: `^\w{4,11}$`
Works fine. It allows the string length between 4 and 11.
I would like it to allow space and special characters like "æ" "ø" "å" (danish characters).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please inform the language or tool you're using.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about `^.{4,11}$`? Or just check that the line lenght is between 4 and 11.
If this is not suitable, I think it is easier to match the characters you **don't** allow...

Answer (score 5):

Since you are talking about .net `\w` should include all unicode code points with the property letter. That means all letters from all languages in Unicode are already available in `\w`

So you just need to add the space and you are done:

```
^[\w ]{4,11}$
```

is matching "Foo æ ø å" in my test.

The '[\w ]' is a character class that includes now all characters included in `\w` and the space. If you need more characters, just add them inside the class.

`\p{L}` would be only the letters, you can use this if you don't want to allow digits.

Comment: Great explation, but I dont see any difference in the behavior compared to ^.{4,11}$

Comment: `.` is any character except newline. `[\w ]` is less, its only characters, digits, `_` (a binding character) and the space. If your string contains e.g. a `,` it will not be matched from my expression.

Comment: So if you don't care about the characters and just you want to check for the length, then `^.{4,11}$` is fine.

Comment: so is "-" (dash) included in \w ?

Comment: No the dash is not included in `\w` see [msdn for a detailed overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

**`^[\wæøå]{4,11}$`**

Comment: Not needed, since the OP is talking about .net all those characters are already included in `\w`