# Apply maximum and minimum limit in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is my **username** regex, i want to apply limit that allow only 3 characters minimum and 15 characters maximum.

```
 /^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[_-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/
```

This Regex Validate below criteria

- Usernames can consist of lowercase and capitals
- Usernames can consist of alphanumeric characters
- Usernames can consist of underscore and hyphens
- Cannot be two underscores, two hypens or two spaces in a row
- Cannot have a underscore, hypen or space at the start or end

Comment: `/^(?=.{3,15}$)[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[_-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385971/regex-min-4-chars-max-11-allow-space-and-special-chars, seems the same?

Comment: space means blank \s character? Usernames can consist of spaces?

Comment: no username can't consist of  spaces

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
^(?=.{3,15}$)[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[_-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
```

Just add a `lookahead`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uE6jQ1/12